# angular-formly datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-formly

I am trying to use the  [angular-formly UI datepicker](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/ui-datepicker) but I can't make it work.

I have already followed the thread bellow and I got nothing.
link: github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-website/issues/15 .

Now the problem is loading the datepicker.html template.
Error Message: Problem loading template for plx/datepicker.html Object { data: "404: Not Found…"

Here is the config:

```
formlyConfig.setType({
  name: 'datepickerPlx',
  templateUrl:  'plx/datepicker.html',
  wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError'],
  defaultOptions: {
    ngModelAttrs: ngModelAttrs,
    templateOptions: {
      datepickerOptions: {
        format: 'MM.dd.yyyy',
        initDate: new Date()
      }
    }
  },
  controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.datepicker = {};

    $scope.datepicker.opened = false;

    $scope.datepicker.open = function ($event) {
      $scope.datepicker.opened = !$scope.datepicker.opened;
    };
  }]
});
```

For more information about the code, here is the  [jsbin code](http://jsbin.com/raxadiyere/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: That location seems like it should be '/plx/datepicker.html' or '../plx/datepicker.html' or something different from what you have it as potentially.  It's giving you an error because it can't find your template.

Comment: @MikeS I do the same for all the others template: 'plx/formly-label-wrapper.html', 'plx/formly-has-error-wrapper.html', 'plx/formly-select-type.html'...  Do you think it is possible to change templateUrl for a template statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the templateUrl for the following code:

```
template: '<input class="form-control" ng-model="model[options.key]" is-open="to.isOpen" datepicker-options="to.datepickerOptions" />',
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it solved my problem, but I did not get the datepicker buttons showing, do you have any guess about it?